# Flutter FirebaseMessaging. Error sending notification: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Object' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```dart
Future<void> sendNotificationToUser(String friendUid, String? title, String? body) async {
  try {
    DocumentSnapshot friendSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(friendUid).get();
    String? friendFcmToken = await friendSnapshot['token_push'];
    print("friendFcmToken $friendFcmToken");

    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    final String? fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    
    if (friendFcmToken != null) {
      await _firebaseMessaging.sendMessage(
        to: friendFcmToken,
        data: {
          'title': title!,
          'body': body!,
        },
      );
      print('Notification sent successfully');
    } else {
      print('Friend user does not have an FCM token');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error sending notification: $e');
  }
}
```

Hello, i'm working with FirebaseMessaging for the first time, and I encountered a problem.

[image]

Please help me figure out what the problem is.

I send notifications in chat.

Comment: form which line you are getting this error?

Comment: await _firebaseMessaging.sendMessage(

Comment: check `fcmToken` by printing i think you are getting null value for that.

Comment: The value is not zero. It is output to the console and and it can be displayed on the screen. Gives the same error even if you use your own token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 data: {
      'title': title ?? '',
      'body': body ?? '',
    },
```

Comment: No, it didn't help

Comment: `String? friendFcmToken = friendSnapshot['token_push'] as String?;`  can you try this?

Comment: The problem remains, maybe i'm dping something wrong ? Can you briefly describe the stages ?

Comment: [https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10951](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10951) sorry